# if this week is empty, don't show this week

Tags: php, sql

My program get weeks in weeks table. And I have challange table and challange_week column in challange table for unite two table.

I want to if gotten week is empty, don't show this week.
Can i do this with just one SQL query?

Comment: SELECT fields FROM weeks WHERE week IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 1):

left outer join?

```
    select * from weeks w
    left outer join challange c on w.week = c.challange_week
    where c.challange_week is not null
```